How to select "From" address when the list of accounts is too long in MS Outlook
Environment:

Windows 11 Pro 64-bit.
Office LTSC Pro Plus 2021 (running locally, not online).
Accounts are POP.

I've added a large number of accounts to MS Outlook. Now, when I compose a new e-mail and click "From" to get the list of accounts to send from:

the list is longer than the height of my display:

When I scroll past the top or bottom of the visible part of the list, the selection highlighting disappears and then after a while reappears at the bottom or top of the list, indicating that the selection was moving among the accounts listed out of view below the bottom of the display.
There are articles online saying to select "Other email address" (example), but I don't seem to have that. How can I select the From address from the full list of accounts?

Edit: An answer has suggested setting up multiple profiles with fewer e-mail accounts in each profile. This solution was also suggested by Microsoft in the chat with them mentioned in my answer. It's not acceptable because it requires shutting down and restarting Outlook to switch between profiles, whereas I want to have Outlook running and constantly receiving e-mails sent to all my addresses.

I have found a workaround for this problem.
The source of the workaround is itself a surprise. I had no idea that Microsoft provides free technical support, but searching for solutions to this problem led me to a Microsoft website with a contact link that got me into a chat with a tech support agent. The agent was not super knowledgeable, but was able to discuss the problem well enough that the workaround sort-of fell out.
And the workaround is also a surprise. To check it, I conducted the following test:

I chose an account whose e-mail address is not visible in the "From" list shown in the question. Because it's not visible, this is an address I can't send from using that list.
I composed an e-mail with that address on the "To" line, and sent it. After doing that, of course, I had two copies of the resulting e-mail, one in the "Sent Items" folder and one in the "Inbox".
I then used each of those two resulting e-mails to compose two more e-mails, one as a "Reply" and one as a "Reply to all". In the four resulting e-mails, I noted the "From" and "To" addresses. The results are as follows:




Folder
How made
Addresses




Sent Items
Reply
Both "From" and "To" are the recipient of the original e-mail.



Reply to all
"From" and "To" addresses are the same as in the original e-mail.


Inbox
Reply
"From" and "To" addresses are swapped from what they were in the original e-mail.



Reply to all
"From" and "To" addresses are swapped from what they were in the original e-mail.



In other words, when working on the copy of the original e-mail sitting in the Inbox, both "Reply" and "Reply to all" give me what I need, which is the ability to compose an e-mail with the hidden e-mail address on the "From" line.
I moved the two copies of the original e-mail, the one in the "Sent Items" folder and the one in the "Inbox", to a new folder. I was able to tell them apart because the one from the Inbox had a slightly larger size and a slightly later timestamp. I then repeated the above test on the e-mails when sitting in that folder. The results were the same as in the above table.
I suppose that if one understands the intricacies of e-mail technology, then one can understand the above results, i.e., the difference in the results of using "Reply" or "Reply to all" and the difference in composing the replies based on the sent or the received e-mail. I do not understand those intricacies, and it would be great if someone would write another answer here explaining these results, or perhaps a comment with a link to a resource that explains them.
In any case, the solution to my problem -- a rather hokey, but workable workaround -- is:

Send a series of e-mails sent to the addresses that are not visible in the "From" list.
When those e-mails are received, move them from the Inbox to a new folder.
When I want to send an e-mail from one of those addresses, simply compose a reply to the e-mail in that folder that was sent to that address.


As a slightly easier workaround, you can also try to create multiple Outlook profiles (Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) to add your accounts in a decentralized manner.

Thank you, but I've edited the question to explain why using multiple profiles is not an acceptable solution.
